# Get client machine name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using the following code. While running in localhost it gives correctly the client machine name, but when i run it the development server, it is not giving the actual result. any idea?

This is an asp.net mvc application.

```
string clientMachineName;
clientMachineName = 
    (Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName);
Response.Write(clientMachineName);
```

I want the computer name or machine name of the client that is making request. The above code gives me an value '172.16.12.100'.

any help much appreciated.

Comment: is this ASP.NET ? what version? pleas add this info into a tag

Comment: Yes, it is in asp.net application

Comment: which result are you getting on the development server? and what is the expected result?

Comment: I want the computer name or machine name of the client that is making request. The above code gives me an value '172.16.12.100'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do realize that, what you are asking and how you are doing is just wrong right?

You need to understand what's an **IP Address** in the first place.

When using `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")` this would never be the "real address",
since no "real address" is ever sent.

An IP address is something used at the network layer, and shouldn't really be used by your application, if you really want the identity of a given machine, you need to use something like [X.509 certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), which are meant to represent an identity (an IP address is not an identity).

You will have problems when a user is behind a NAT, and you will never get the correct identity of an user.

That is why under localhost everything works fine but soon you want something outside your "box" everything starts to go bad.

Comment: Even in intranet case we wont be able to get client machine name?

Comment: In intranet environment, you should use Windows Authentication to pull up from the Active Directory the identity of the user itself, not the machine as I can login with my own credentials in my colleague machine.

Comment: Thats not a problem,in our network every machine will have different machine name.

Comment: I wasn't specifying that you have problems in the machine name, but that you probably want the user that is accessing your application and not the computer itself as everyone can use a different machine, or he machine is down and he/she will login from other machine and you probably want that user.

Comment: I dont need to bother aabout the all the scenario u told. could you please tell me whether the code i wrote will work in intranet case.

Comment: This is because we are working for some purpose based on machine name. thats why :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Dns.GetHostEntry Method (String)` method queries a DNS server for the IP address that is associated with a host name or IP address. This would probably not work on a remote network because you aren't querying the same DNS server.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You aren't guaranteed to get that information on a remote network. I'm assuming your dev server is not on the same network.